# MySql database data parsing issue

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofp1M.png)}

```
private void btn_process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
connection_class.open_connection();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `invoice`( `registerNumber`,`vehicleModel`,`fuelType`,`km`,`mechanicName`,`date`,`job1`,`job2`,`job3`,`job4`,`job5`,`job6`,`job7`,`job8`,`discount`,`price`)  VALUES (@registerNumber,@vehicleModel,@fuelType,@km,@mechanicName,@date,@job1,@job2,@job3,@job4,@job5,@job6,@job7,@job8,@discount,@price)", connection_class.con);
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registerNumber", txt_vehicleNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicleModel", txt_vehicleModle);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fuelType", drp_fuelType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@km", txt_km);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mechanicName", drp_mechanic);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", lbl_date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job1", lbl_job1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job2", lbl_job2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job3", lbl_job3);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job4", lbl_job4);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job5", lbl_job5);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job6", lbl_job6);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job7", lbl_job7);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job8", lbl_job8);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", lbl_totDiscount);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", lbl_total);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection_class.close_connection();
            MessageBox.Show("Invoice printed !!!");
}
```

I want to send those data to the table properly.
Eg : Instead of "Guna.UI2.WinForms.Internal.PlaceholderTextBox, Text: 343447.00" this i want to send "343447"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that custom overrides of `ToString` are invoked on the object passed to `AddWithValue`, you need to access corresponding properties on them (depending on object), for example something like the following:

```cs
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job1", lbl_job1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job2", lbl_job2.Text);
```

Also do not use `AddWithValue` because [`AddWithValue` is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), use `AddParameter` with explicit type. For example:

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add("@job1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lbl_job1.Text;
```

or

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@job1", SqlDbType.VarChar)
{
    Value = lbl_job1.Text
});
```